# Slow execution SQL query within the application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to execute a query from my application which is based on asp.net. I'm using ADO commands to execute a function in the Azure SQL database. My application has high traffic during the work hours and this particular query takes too long to execute and eventually times out. I then have to use the below command to clear out the cache which fixes the issue temporarily:

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION CLEAR PROCEDURE_CACHE;
```

the query takes less than a second to execute from SSMS. After clearing the cache by using the above command, it works fine for a few days then the issue comes back.

Can someone help me understand what's the correlation between clearing cache and execution time in the asp.net application. How can I fix it permanently?

Comment: This is a must read - [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?]( http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Good Question!! waiting for Good answer to come!

Comment: **[Parameter Sniffing Problem and Possible Workarounds](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/)**